# no mapred-site.xml in /etc/hadoop/conf.dist in CDH4.4

Tags: hdfs, cloudera

In cloudera CDH 4.4, /etc/hadoop/conf.dist is supposed to contain files that should be copied into another directory and modified

I can't find mapred-site.xml in this directory (hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml are present).

Comment: Did you install YARN instead of MapReduce as a service? In that case you still have MapReduce but v2 not v1 and its really part of YARN and configured in its config files.